# Is there a shortcut to move focus to the sidebar in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It would be very useful for me if there was a keyboard shortcut for moving focus to the sidebar in Visual Studio Code. I have seen the question [Is there a shortcut to hide the side bar in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878856/is-there-a-shortcut-to-hide-the-side-bar-in-visual-studio-code) but this is not what I want.

I want to get focus there without using the mouse so that I can select another file listed in the sidebar without having to use the mouse.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

**<kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd><kbd>`0`</kbd>** is the default binding of *View: Focus into Side Bar* command that focuses sidebar regardless what it shows at the moment - be it Explorer, Source Control, Extensions or any other pane. (Or reveals its last visible state.)

Zero (<kbd>`0`</kbd>) in this key combination represents character that *"English-keyboard-layout" zero key in the top 'numerical' row* produces in current regional keyboard layout.  It is **not** the zero key in the "*NumPad*".

Like most other commands it is discoverable either in the *Command Palette* (<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>):

[image: command palette with query: (greater-than sign) focus sidebar. Sole highlighted result reads "View: focus into Side Bar", words "focus" and "side bar" are emphasized. Keyboard shortcut hint reads "Ctrl + é" (control key plus Latin letter E with acute)]

(N.B. `é` instead of `0` due to aforementioned regional layout in effect), or in the *Keyboard Shortcuts* settings page (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>):

[image: VSC Keyboard Shortcuts settings with query "focus sidebar" showing sole Command result: "Focus into Side Bar", words "focus" and "side bar" are emphasized. There is the command ID that reads "workbench.action.focusSideBar"]

---

Btw <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> .. <kbd>3</kbd> focuses editor groups respectively.

---

If you'd like to have this (or other) key combination to act like **two way "focus toggle" between editor and sidebar** (like `Show Explorer` behaves), you can alter your settings accordingly using distinct actions with identical key combination differentiated by excluding [`"when"`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts) conditions.  Resulting part of `keybindings.json` would then be:

```js
  { // Unbind unconditional default using "minus" (-) before command
    "key": "ctrl+0",
    "command": "-workbench.action.focusSideBar"
  },
  { // Move focus to the SideBar if not (!) there
    "key": "ctrl+0",
    "when": "!sideBarFocus",
    "command": "workbench.action.focusSideBar"
  },
  { // Move focus to the Editor, if currently in the SideBar
    "key": "ctrl+0",
    "when": "sideBarFocus",
    "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup"
  },
```

Comment: Once focus lands in the sidebar, it seems to get stuck. That is, when the Explorer tab is open, pressing Control+0 moves focus to the sidebar, but then when you try to navigate through the tree nothing happens. The arrow keys do nothing. The tab key does nothing. So far it appears that Visual Studio Code is in violation of WCAG Guideline 2.1, specifically 2.1.2 No Keyboard Trap (http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#keyboard-operation-trapping).

Comment: Yes, sometimes there are some border cases where keyboard navigation appears to be stuck, but overal VSC developers invests a lot of efforts making it as keaboard accessible as possible: there is a bunch of workarounds for such situations: ctrl+q, command palette or advice shown in alt+f1 dialog.

Comment: Anyway, if you can reproduce some nasty keyboard trap (best in a clean profile, https://stackoverflow.com/q/49667641) it would be definitely worth reporting at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/

Comment: I tried to reproduce the keyboard trap issue I encountered again today and I could not. I did install an update for Visual Studio Code today so perhaps they fixed it already.

Answer (score 32):

These are the different shortcuts to focus on the various components(in order of the icons) of the sidebar.

1. File Explorer: <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>
2. Search: <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>
3. Source Control: <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>
4. Debug: <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>
5. Extensions: <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>

To toggle the visibility of the sidebar, just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>

Comment: Perfect subset of commonly repeated operations, thanks.

Comment: Is there any short cut to focus editor panel?

Comment: @LiuHao You can use `ctrl+1` to do so.

Answer (score 13):

`Cmd` + `Shift` + `E` works for me. See screenshot

[image]

Comment: As well on my mac.

Answer (score 7):

you can hover over the icons in the sidebar if you want a tooltip telling you what shortcut each tab has

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am aware of a shortcut `Ctrl + B` to toggle the sidebar open and close.

Answer (score 0):

Mine, on windows, numpad key doesn't work. I have to use the other Zero key that is on the top of the keyboard.

[image]