# Navigation in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't figure out how to navigate between the file browser, editor and terminal. I know there must be keyboard shortcuts to do this, but I can't figure it out. I'm using mainly Linux Manjaro (for now) but I also have another laptop with Mint. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49662075/11107541,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/42796887/11107541

Answer (score 0):

For switching between editor and terminal already exists <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> and to change focus to files in the explorer you need to add a keyboard shortcut. Open the Command Palette by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.

Then type “Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)” and press Enter. This will open the keybindings.json file. Add the following entry to this file:

```
{
        "key": "ctrl+shift+0",
        "command": "workbench.explorer.fileView.focus"
 }
```

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> but you could use other key combination that is not previously in use.

For further reference here are the official keyboard [shortcuts for Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf), [shortcuts for Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf) and [shortcuts for macOS.](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Right after I asked this question I found an article that basically laid out about 1000 ways to do this. At this time I haven't even finished reading the entire article. I also found a short YouTube video that showed how to switch focus between the File Explorer and Editor by ctrl + shift + E and between the editor and terminal by by ctrl + `.

Wow. This went from 0 to way too much in nothing  flat. Thank you for the information.