# is there any atom style file tree close and open functionality available for vscode?

Tags: editor, atom-editor, visual-studio-code

[image]

> is this kind of feature available in vs code?. Where i can just click
>   and open the side panel.

Comment: Took a look, and didn't see an obvious way to add this. Are you ok using a keyboard shortcut? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30883535/4722345

Comment: thanx for the suggestion . shortcut will a nicer option