# New to VSCode, can't disable sidebar

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am new to VSCode, long been a holdout with Powershell ISE. I am in a situation where I am doing more with PS7, so have no choice but to use it. The one thing that I cannot seem to find is a way to permanently disable the sidebar. Every time I run a script the stupid thing pops up, and I have to hit CTRL+B to close it. I have tried going into Powershell language specific settings, but the only option I see is sidebar.location.

Is there any way to permanently stop this from popping up?

Comment: Is your script(s) opening a file?  So that disabling `Explorer > Auto Reveal` would help.

Comment: Just run the script from the terminal? If you are running using the debugger or F5 then what is the expectation there?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

1. go to settings
2. search for Debug: Open Debug
3. choose never open

Answer (score 1):

Allow me just say this. I too use VSCode, Sapien's PS Studio, and the ISE more than the previous two, but also use PowerShell v7.

So, FYI... You do have a choice, You can use PowerShell v7 from the ISE. I do this every day. Well, it's a workaround to do so, but it works just fine.

Here is one of the ways to use PowerShell v7 in the ISE.

> [Using PowerShell Core 6 and 7 in the Windows PowerShell ISE](https://ironmansoftware.com/using-powershell-core-6-and-7-in-the-windows-powershell-ise)

The other way I use it is just shelling/branching out to it as needed.

Yet, your question is really a duplicate of this Q&A.

> [Is there a shortcut to hide the sidebar in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878856/is-there-a-shortcut-to-hide-the-side-bar-in-visual-studio-code)

And these potential answers...

> you can hide the activity bar by setting up your own keybinding
>   (code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings) for
>   workbench.action.toggleActivityBarVisibility

and or

> In the VS code version 1.43, you can hide or show the side menu or
>   activity bar by going under the 'VIEW' tab in the nav bar in the top
>   margin of VS CODE(called the 'Menu Bar'). Go to View => Appearance,
>   there you can check or uncheck different nav bars to show/hide each
>   one.
>
> If you have the top bar (Menu Bar) currently hidden press 'alt' key to
>   bring it back then follow above instructions to check it to keep it
>   there permanently if desired.

The thing to remember though is, that sidebar is your file/project explorer and as such critical for normal development. It's how you get to all your files. Sure, you can still get to them using F1 and type a name, but that's kind of painful, vs scrolling to find what you need or opening multiple files in a project at once.

Comment: It appears the OP knows how to hide the side bar (he mentions Ctrl+B) - it just doesn't stay hidden when he runs the script for some reason.     So it isn't a duplicate of the question you cited.   And it is on-topic `software tools commonly used by programmers;` from https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: `Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless** they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.` from https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. (emphasis added)

Comment: Using the View menu in VSCode, and unchecking 'Show Sidebar' does prevent the sidebar from appearing on code runs or restart of VScode. So, his use case is prudent to that Q&A. I know, this because I've done it myself. Primarily when doing demos of features to sessions I deliver.

Comment: @postanote Thanks, I will check those links out. I will say though, I cannot replicate your last comment "Using the View menu and unchecking 'Show Sidebar' does prevent the sidebar from appearing..." I have tried this, but it continues to pop back up for me on next code run.

Comment: Interesting, that it comes back for you, as I've not ever had this happen. I've had other odd/frustrating things happen regularly in VScode, just not this one. I am going to assume you are using the latest build, but give the Preview builds a shot, as they are still really stable.